# Inherit all css properties from parent div to child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html,

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">

    </div>

</div>
```

css looks like,

```
#parent{
height:100px;
width:200px;
any-aother-property1:something;
any-aother-property2:something;
any-aother-property3:something;
}
```

Is there is any way to inherit all the properties to child at once , means can I do like,

```
$('#child').properties= $('#parent').properties
```

Answer (score 17):

If you really want to dynamically inherit **all** CSS properties given to the parent **at runtime**, you can do the following.

**Caution:** This overrides the default value for all properties. Generally speaking, it is wise to assume that defaults are correct until proven otherwise. Some properties are `inherit` by default and some are not for various reasons. So you probably should only override specific properties that need to be changed.

```css
#child {
    all: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Note: this almost definitely is not what is intended by the question, even though it literally answers the question.  all inherits "all properties including those not normally inheritable"

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this is probably not what you want"?  Are there no cases where this woudl be useful?

Comment: @JimB I elaborated the caution note :)

Answer (score 6):

is this enough?

```
#parent, #parent > div {
    /* your properties */
}
```

Comment: What if I really don't know all the parents css properties until run-time ?

Comment: Why do this when you can only give the child id? It is simpler.

Comment: @Flopet17 because ids in css are evil. I would rather do #parent, #parent .inheritStyle {...} though. And add class='inheritStyle' to the child. Or even better just give them both class='myStyle' and style .myStyle by css.

Comment: @Fledgling I've found this: http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-copy-style-copycss hope it helps

Comment: @Fledgling I would personally just define a css style for class .myStyle {} and then add the myStyle classname to both parent and child. Or are you setting inline style of the parent by javascript at runtime? Then you will need to do document.getElementById('child').style = document.getElementById('parent').style; every time the parent style changes.

Answer (score 2):

Copy inline:

```
$('#child').get(0).style = $('#parent').get(0).style;
```

But better if you find a CSS way as stated in the other answers.

UPDATE:

Get all styles:

```
$('#child').get(0).style = window.getComputedStyle($('#parent').get(0), null);
```

Comment: This will only inherit the style that are given inline to the parent .However if any css is given using class , it won't inherit those .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such a thing but you can always do something like this:

```
#parent, #child{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    any-aother-property1:something;
    any-aother-property2:something;
    any-aother-property3:something;
}
```

Add both id's to have the same properties.

Comment: What if I really don't know all the parents css properties until run-time ?

Answer (score 1):

I have added a function in my library, [custags.js](https://obnoxiousnerd.github.io/custags.js) which will help you doing that.

This is the `extendcss()` which requires the query selectors of the elements or the other methods to function.
You can do this with any type of elements, let it be equals or parent-child.

Here is the working demo:-

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
const child = document.querySelector('.child');
Ω('#button').on('click', ()=>{
Ω('document').extendcss(parent, child);
});
```

```css
.parent{
background-color: teal;
color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://obnoxiousnerd.github.io/custags.js/custags.min.js"></script>
<h1 class = "parent">Parent</h1>
<h1 class = "child">Child</h1>
<button id="button">Give child some css</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since children inherit most of their parent's styles by default, you can focus on clearing the child's styles rather than setting them equal to the parent's.

In Chrome and Opera, you can do so with one line of code:

```
$('#child')[0].style.all= 'unset';
```

This works whether `child`'s CSS properties are in a style sheet or are created dynamically.

To clear dynamically-created CSS only, you can do this in all modern browsers:

```
$('#child')[0].style.cssText= '';
```

That will restore the style sheet properties.

The cross-browser solution to your problem may be the following:

```
var cs= getComputedStyle($('#child')[0]);
for (var i=0 ; i<cs.length; i++) {
  $('#child').css(cs[i], 'inherit');
}
```

This iterates through all of `child`'s styles, setting them to be inherited from the parent.

You can test each of these methods in different browsers at this Fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/9c3sy2eb/7/**