# Unable to affect child elements with css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

When putting CSS classes on element parents. I can't get text to change for the child elements, is there a reason for this? My current code:

```
<Box 
   //does not effect all child elements                  
                  sx={{
                    color: 'red',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: 'medium',
                  }}>
                <Typography
    //element changes
                  sx={{
                    color: 'red',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: 'medium',
                  }}
                >
                  Salary: $30,000
                </Typography>
                <Typography>Year groups: Y1 - Y5</Typography>
                <Typography>Period: Full Time, Permanent</Typography>
                <Typography>Start time: 9:00am</Typography>
                <Typography>Start date: 01/04/2021</Typography>
                <Typography>NQT Required</Typography>
                <Typography>Apply by: 14 Jan 2002</Typography>
                <Typography>Job was posted: 16 Dec 2021</Typography>
</Box>
```

Comment: `Typography` probably has default styles which override any parent styles. To customize Typography, you'll have to directly override Typography styles.

Comment: I don't think that all css properties are inherited by default. If you want to dynamically inherit properties you have to declare them with <your-property> : inherit; to inherit from parents css (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997355/inherit-all-css-properties-from-parent-div-to-child-div).

Comment: Harkunwar is right, if you run only the code that you posted it works fine. It's probably styling that you set to your Typography.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a css file, with the custom edits you wanna add to the Typography, but you will add `!important` at the end of each property.

```
.example{ color:"red" !important }
```

that will override the default color of material-ui